# Running AJAX function from button dropdown

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a jquery bootstrap type dropdown from here: http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-dropdown/

I am using it to create a dropdown on an existing button that I have already created. Mu=y button fires an AJAX call that runs a query and removes the row from the screen. I need a way call the AJAX from the new dropdown rather than from the existing button. Ive tried changing classes and that didnt work. Here is my code:

dropdown

```
<div id="dropdown-1" class="dropdown dropdown-tip">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#1">Previously discussed and <br>customer not interested 
</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2">Customer has preferred supplier or price
</a></li>
        <li><a href="#3">Customer does not have authority to purchase
</a></li>

        <li><a href="#4">Data inaccuracy/ no real opportunity
</a></li>
        <li><a href="#5">Other 
</a></li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

AJAX

```
$(function() {
$(".decline").click(function(){

var element = $(this);
var del_id = element.attr("id");
var order_id = element.attr("data-order");
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "decline.php",
   //data: info,
   data: {id1:del_id,order_id1:order_id},
   success: function(){cache: false}
});
  $(this).parents(".show").animate({ backgroundColor: "#003" }, "slow")
  .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");

});
});
```

Existing button

```
<a href="#" class="decline" id="<?php echo $id1; ?>" data-order="<?php echo $name; ?>"><input type="button" title="accept" value="Accept" /></a>
```

I want to duplicate the button function for each dropdown entry so the user can click on any entry in the dropdown and run the AJAX function.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a button with a class `decline` (referring the statement `$(".decline").click(function(){`)?

Comment: Where did you declared **decline** class element? I think it should be **.dropdown-menu li a**, but as I can see there is no attribute named id1 or data-order1.

Comment: sorry..I copied the wrong one from netbeans..I just updated the code and the class in the above example.

Comment: Still what about the attributes - `id1` and `data-order1` in the Ajax call? Statements - `var del_id = element.attr("id1");
var order_id = element.attr("data-order1");`

Comment: Theyre being passed by via the link; I updated my labels above.

Comment: You want the Ajax to be called upon clicking the dropdown `li's` and not the button. So the `li's a` should have that `decline` class and the `id`, `data-order` attributes and not the button.

Comment: Or change the Ajax call statement as `$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){`. And `li a` should be `<li><a href="#1" id="<?php echo $id1; ?>" data-order="<?php echo $name; ?>">>Previously discussed and <br>customer not interested 
</a></li>`.

Comment: Thanks for the help; Ive tried both solutions and neither worked for me.

Comment: If it hasn't worked yet then can you copy here the code that you have tried after applying either of the solutions?

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me -

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-dropdown/jquery.dropdown.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-dropdown/jquery.dropdown.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <a href="#" data-dropdown="#dropdown-1">dropdown</a>

    <div id="dropdown-1" class="dropdown dropdown-tip">
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#1" id="1" data-order="a">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#2" id="2" data-order="b">Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#3" id="3" data-order="c">Item 3</a></li>

            <li class="dropdown-divider"></li>

            <li><a href="#4">Item 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#5">Item 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#5">Item 6</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="dropdown-1" class="dropdown dropdown-tip">
        <div class="dropdown-panel">
            You can put whatever HTML you want in a panel!
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function($) {
            $('.dropdown li a').click(function() {
                var element = $(this);
                var del_id = element.attr("id");
                var order_id = element.attr("data-order");
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "decline.php",
                    data: {id1:del_id,order_id1:order_id},
                    success: function(){cache: false}
                });
                $(this).parents(".show")
                    .animate({ backgroundColor: "#003" }, "slow")
                    .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");

                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Upon clicking each of the items from the menu list, a separate Ajax call is made.

Change it according to your needs.

I hope it helps.